# Create a simple form application to edit a textfile

Tags: java, macos, pyqt

I think I need to restate my question ...

I want to create a SIMPLE form application that edits certain areas of one very specific text file. Though I have some web development experience, I do not want to create a browser based application. Basically I want to give a Desktop application a try and I am looking for some help to get started including suggestions for the language of choice. The application should run on Mac OS X. Besides there's no restriction: Java, Cocoa, Python, even a some interactive shell script would be ok.

If you are interested in the details, continue to read here, but not that my question is not LaTex specific...:
I have an automatically generated report file that contains LaTex Code. Now I want to build a little application that creates a form field for every section and it's header. The document contains only a few hundred lines and the should work the following:

```
\section{ This is were the header text should go inside the document  }
\normalsize{ This is where the normal text should go}
```

The header / normalsize pairs occur 5-6 times within the document. All I want is a little GUI that allows user to edit between the curly braces without seeing any TeX code. I know that there's LyX and other WYSIWYG approaches to LaTeX – I do not want to reinvent the wheel. I just want to protect the auto-generated code a litte from users and make it a little more comfortable to them.

EDIT: 
here's my very first try. I guess I should use PlainDocument instead of directly sending it, but I´ll figure that out, since I got plenty of help from trashgod with the editor / Text Component links. The major problem is to single out the content from \section{} and \normalsize{} stuff. Probably I will some regexp here. I need to get a new text area for every appearance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.swing.*;

public class basicFrame extends JFrame {
// Declare Variables

    JScrollPane bildlauf = new JScrollPane();
    JTextArea txtfeld = new JTextArea();

    public basicFrame() {
        super();


        // Main window
        setTitle("ReportEditor");
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        // components 
        try {
            File datei = new File("report.Rnw");
            FileReader in = new FileReader(datei);
            txtfeld.read(in, datei);
            in.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error !");
        }

        // setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        // Scroll Shizzle
        bildlauf.getViewport().add(txtfeld, null);
        getContentPane().add(bildlauf, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //txtfeld.setSize(500,680);
        //add(txtfeld);
        //this.getContentPane().add(txtfeld);

        // close
        addWindowListener(new WindowLauscher());
    }

    // event handlers... 
    protected static final class WindowLauscher extends WindowAdapter {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Fesnter erzeugen und anzeigen, die main Sache halt
        basicFrame hf = new basicFrame();
        hf.setSize(500, 700);
        hf.setLocation(100, 100);
        hf.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Thx in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Actually php scripts can be run from the command line, you just need to install the interpreter, not a web server

Comment: Did not know that, just knew it for python. Though it would not help my case. If I don't trust the user to let him edit a .tex document I don't want him to install some interpreter ... Anyway I've learned something :)

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TeX on Mac OS X](http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php?title=Editors#jEdit) wiki recommends [jEdit](http://jedit.sourceforge.net/), which supports [plugins](http://plugins.jedit.org/). [LaTeXTools](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?LaTeXTools) might be a good start.

Addendum:

> I do not want to reinvent the wheel.
>   All I want to do is create a form application.

Although these goals are somewhat contradictory, you can always parse the file and use a suitable [`JTextComponent`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html) for each editable section. Here's an overview of [*Using Text Components*](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html); see [*Text Component Features*](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) if you want to create your own editor kit, as discussed in [*Customizing a Text Editor*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/text/editor_kit/index.html).

Addendum: In addition to the tutorial, you might look at this [text field layout example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175280). Also, consider a two-column [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), which would allow you to cleanly separate your document model from your form view.

Addendum: A few notes on your code.

1. Class names are usually capitalized, e.g. `BasicFrame`.
2. Don't extend `JFrame` if you're not changing it's behavior; `JPanel` is a good container for other components, and it can be displayed in a `JFrame`.
3. Always buid your GUI on the [EDT](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
4. Keep you view and model [separate](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/).

Comment: Thx for the interesting links, but I am looking for a start to build my own "editor". Eh, not editor. All I wanna do is create a form application.

Comment: @ran2: I've elaborated above.

Comment: thx! the elaborated version really helps. I will work through it. Java seems a good choice too.

Comment: @ran2: Excellent; I've added two additional links.

Comment: thx again. Particularly the SO thread looks pretty helpful. I just posted my very initial code in the latest edit. Feel free to laugh, it's my second Java "program" – if you count "hello world" as a program.

Comment: @trashgod: Thanks for pointing me into the right place within the help.In case you stumble across more helpful links in your library... feel free to post them ;) . What would also be very helpful is some complete code (as opposed to only snippets in the help). Of course it does not have to be specifically my example since I don't want you to my work, but something that helps to understand how files and classes work together over different files – particularly for this MVC thing.Eh, and is there a way download these help files as whole that you keep sending?I am a commuter :)

Comment: @ran2: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ is the top, but I don't see download. I think `JTable` for the view and `AbstractTableModel` for the model is the way to go; the tutorial has complete examples.

Comment: found no downloadable file either.. now I really got something to work through before I get back here... :)