# Components in GridLayout wit JPanel fills the grid incorrectly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, grid-layout

I am trying to prevent the GridLayout in a JPanel from filling the cells entirely and ignoring any setSize of the components

i am using this code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GrideComponents{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Laying Out Components in a Grid");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,2,0,0));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Enter name"));
    JTextField a = new JTextField(5);
    a.setSize(10, 10);
    panel.add(a);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Enter Roll"));
    panel.add(new JTextField(3));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Enter Class"));
    panel.add(new JTextField(3));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Enter Total Marks"));
    panel.add(new JTextField(3));
    panel.add(new JButton("Ok"));
    panel.add(new JButton("Cancel"));
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

And every component is filling the gris cell instead of being in the size specified.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) so you understand the basics of how layout managers work.

A GridLayout resizes all components to the same size.

When creating a form you will generally nest different panels using different layout managers to get the effect you desire.

In this case you might use a FlowLayout for the buttons. Then you might use a GridBagLayout or SpringLayout for the other components.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try what you suggested. in the meanwhile, I've just created a few panels with grid layouts to place my components better.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting setMaximumSize and setPreferredSize?

In any case, I recommend you try [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) for all your layout needs. You'll be surprised by it's simplicity!

Comment: GridLayout is a simple layout manager with simple rules. I was going to downvote for the same reason as explained by jackrabbit. I believe people should know how the default layout managers work before using/recommending 3rd party libraries.

Comment: While I agree with this, I believe MiGLayout could be an exception because a) this single layout manager can replace ALL built-in managers b) it's really small in size (~75 kb) and c) http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6530906 (many want it to be included in JDK 7)

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of GridLayout is to layout the components in a regular grid. Your `setSize` calls will be overridden by the layout manager. Possibly `setPreferredSize` or `setMaximumSize` may work, but it is up to the layout manager to decide to take them into account.

Comment: -1, using setPreferredSize() or setMaximumSize() will have no effect when using a GridLayout. Read the API documentation or read the Swing tutorial. The whole point of a GridLayout is that EVERY component is resized to the size of the largest component added to the grid.

Comment: That's why I said: "possibly ... may work, but up to the layout manager". The OP can read the documentation too, no?

Answer (score 0):

[`BoxLayout`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) is a useful alternative in this context, as seen in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175280).