# Multiple JPanel with different width inside a JFrame using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to create two panels with different width in a JFrame. I want my right panel to have twice the width of my left panel. I'm trying to use GridBagLayout by using gridwidth = 1 for my leftpanel and gridwidth = 2 for my rightpanel. But instead of getting different width, I'm getting two panels with same width. What should I change? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AppFrame2 extends JFrame {

    GridBagLayout gbl;
    GridBagConstraints gbc;
    JPanel leftpanel;
    JPanel rightpanel;

    public AppFrame2() {
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        // Settning Frame Layout
        gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        this.setLayout(gbl);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;

        // Add Panels
        leftpanel = new JPanel();
        leftpanel.setBackground(Color.green);
        this.addPanels(0, 0, 1, 1, leftpanel); // row, col, height, width component

        rightpanel = new JPanel();
        rightpanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        this.addPanels(0, 1, 1, 2, rightpanel);
    }

    private void addPanels(int row, int col, int height, int width,
        Component com) {
        gbc.gridx = col;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        gbc.gridheight = height;
        gbc.gridwidth = width;
        gbl.setConstraints(com, gbc);
        this.getContentPane().add(com);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AppFrame2();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using internal padding?

Comment: The reason they are being resized is because a GridBagLayout references things to be the same size. reference this for a better example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112886/components-in-gridlayout-wit-jpanel-fills-the-grid-incorrectly

Comment: I used gbc.insets(2, 2, 2, 2) , 
but then i removed it. I don't know about any other padding. Could you please give an example.

Comment: @Dacotah I used GridBagLayout before with JButton. Then I was able to give width or height to a button. I thought i could do the same with JPanel. I'm new to GUI programming. Sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not specifying the widths of the columns. Adding the line `gbl.columnWidths = new int[] {500/3, 500/3*2};` will set the widths of the columns to how you want them to be. I added the lines to your code here to make it work :)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AppFrame2 extends JFrame {

    GridBagLayout gbl;
    GridBagConstraints gbc;
    JPanel leftpanel;
    JPanel rightpanel;

    public AppFrame2() {
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        // Settning Frame Layout
        gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        //************* New code **************//
        gbl.columnWidths = new int[] {500/3, 500/3*2};
        gbl.rowHeights = new int[] {500};
        gbl.columnWeights = new double[] {1, 1};
        gbl.rowWeights = new double[] {1};
        //************* End code **************//

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        this.setLayout(gbl);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;

        // Add Panels
        leftpanel = new JPanel();
        leftpanel.setBackground(Color.green);
        this.addPanels(0, 0, 1, 1, leftpanel); // row, col, height, width component

        rightpanel = new JPanel();
        rightpanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        this.addPanels(0, 1, 1, 2, rightpanel);
    }

    private void addPanels(int row, int col, int height, int width,
                           Component com) {
        gbc.gridx = col;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        gbc.gridheight = height;
        gbc.gridwidth = width;
        gbl.setConstraints(com, gbc);
        this.getContentPane().add(com);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AppFrame2();
    }

}
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to specify: When you add this line of code, it allows the constraints to know which grid position you are adding it into. Without specifying, it will create the position with no specifications.

Comment: No problem! =D Any time.