# Instead of equal width, could elements in my GridLayout take only as much space as needed?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, grid-layout

I have such `JPanel`:

```
container = new JPanel();
container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
```

In this panel, I put `JLabel` and `JTextField` to create classical form. It renders like this:

[image: image description]

Obviously, I'd prefer to have the first column shorter, specifically just as wide as necessary to fit all JLabels. Like this (mspaint figure):

[image: image description]

The gray dashed line indicates where the two columns are divided. What do you propose for this layout?

Note that the second column may also contain check box, select box or some other form element.

Comment: Use a GridBagLayout...

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of equal width, could elements in my GridLayout take only as much space as needed?

No, it is designed to give elements equal width (and height).  If the UI needs different widths, use another layout like `GroupLayout` or `GridBagLayout`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21659516/418556) for an MCVE of doing it using `GroupLayout`.

[image]

Comment: From the image and the code it doesn't seem like introducing different widths for both columns - so it doesn't seem to do what I need. Also, everytime I tried to use GridBaglayout everything went broken, so I avoid it.

Comment: *"From the image and the code.."*  Did you actually try swapping the long fields for all short fields?!?  *"..everytime I tried to use GridBaglayout everything went broken.."*  GBL can be tricky to use, but we sure can't help you debug code we cannot see.  Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) like the code I linked to.