# Java Swing Multiinput Second JTextField on the second row

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

i am not really familiar with JPanel and kinda stuck at one thing.
I want to know how to make second JTextfield on the second row.
They appear to be on the same row.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class JOptionPaneMultiInput {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JTextField xField = new JTextField(5);
      JTextField yField = new JTextField(5);

      JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("x:"));
      myPanel.add(xField);
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("y:"));
      myPanel.add(yField);

      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, 
           "Please Enter X and Y Values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      }
   }
```

Comment: First you should study about layout manager in java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI.  It seems you want rows of label/value pairs.  This can be achieved best using `GridBagLayout` or `GroupLayout` - here is an [example using `GroupLayout`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21659516/418556). Though I've also create the effect using nested panels (two `GridLayout` panels in a `BorderLayout`) ..

Comment: BTW - `JTextField xField = new JTextField(5);` consider using a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` instead - the user would prefer that for selecting numbers.

Answer (score 3):

It is the matter of layouts in java. In this case you should use `GridLayout`. Maybe it's better for you to study a little bit about layouts in java.

For now it's good to test `GridLayout` in your example:

```
public class JOptionPaneMultiInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextField xField = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField yField = new JTextField(5);

        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("x:"));
        myPanel.add(xField);
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("y:"));
        myPanel.add(yField);

        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
                "Please Enter X and Y Values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    }
}
```

But for more complex GUI designs in swing please refer to `GridBagLayout` or `GroupLayout`. In real world applications, most of the times you may use more than one layout.

Good Luck.

Comment: While `GridLayout` might not have as ..visually appealing an end effect as the other suggestions you mention, it sure is the *easiest* way to achieve the requirement of multiple rows.  :)

Comment: *"As always you are right"*  LOL!  I wish it were (always) true.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: It is true! You are my good friend and I always count on your answers.