# GridBagLayout is Missing from Palette

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to build a GUI for a program I just finished writing. I don't have any prior experience with building a GUI, but I have found enough online to get started.

I initially used the GridLayout and got the setup I wanted, however, I found that I couldn't resize any of the components. Instead, when the program launches, they are at their smallest size. After some research, I found that the GridLayout doesn't allow for resizing and that the GridBagLayout would be a much better solution though it is more complicated. I cannot find this layout in the palette and have been unable to find anyone with the same issue in a few google searches. Does anyone know if I might be missing something obvious?

Here is the image of the options that show up for layouts.
[image: Image showing layouts in windowBuilder]

Comment: This is an IDE specific issue (that I don't know which IDE is), but you can always do it by-hand for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39218726/2180785) and is usually recommended, as your IDE will generate unreadable code and which will be harder to maintain.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I will give that a shot. I use Eclipse, but I wouldn't have expected that to be the issue which I suppose is why this was stumping me.

Comment: Well, maybe Netbeans has `GridBagLayout` or maybe IntelliJ does have it, all of them use their own Interface Builder, that's why it's suggested to create the layout by yourself without any Interface Builder, that way it's portable and if you have any issue you can ask here by creating a MRE and we won't need a specific IDE to run your code, the same happens if you use a versioning tool (git for example), your code can be run anywhere :)