# Swing JComponents alignment like form

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jcomponent

How to align these JComponents like a Form on center of the Content pane...using Swing

```
        panel1.add(l1);
        panel1.add(c1);
        panel1.add(l2);
        panel1.add(c2);
        panel1.add(b4);
        panel1.add(b5);
        frame1.getContentPane().add(panel1);
```

Please help me

Comment: *"l1.. c1"*  Gee.  Can you possibly vague that up for me?  Are the l's labels, the c's combos., the b's buttons?  Also draw some ASCII art or an image to show the intended layout.  Forms can be laid out a lot of different ways.  I suspect a nested layout or `GroupLayout` would be best for this, but I won't be looking into it without more information.

Answer (score 6):

How about you read the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) tutorial first? I abuse this saying but, *there's always more than one way to skin a cat*

---

Here's a superfluous example that uses [`BoxLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) and [`setAlignmentX(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAlignmentX%28float%29) on the [`JComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) instances -

```
public final class StackComponentsDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();             
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel.add(new DisabledJButton());
        panel.add(new DisabledJButton());
        panel.add(new DisabledJButton());
        panel.add(new DisabledJButton());
        panel.add(new DisabledJButton());

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final class DisabledJButton extends JButton{
        public DisabledJButton(){
            super("Disabled");
            setEnabled(false);
            setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: always there and very fast +1

Comment: +1 for `BoxLayout` w/example. See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174765/variable-layout-in-swing/3175280#3175280), which adds labels.

Answer (score 2):

Check [SpringLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) if it fits your needs. If not, probably [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) will do.

Here's an [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/SpringFormProject/src/layout/SpringForm.java) of using SpringLayout for simple form-like layout.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the boxlayout manager.  Using the layout managers without the help of an IDE takes some time and practice.  More information can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails you can always try: http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/javadevtools/wbpro/layoutmanagers/swing/index.html

I was really impressed with window builder, it generates nice and clean code and is easily integrated into eclipse.