# Using scrollbars with absolute layout in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, absolutelayout

I am not able to use scroll bars with absolute layout in Swing.

I don't wish to use this layout but I have to display dynamic objects on my panel on click of a button and align them using `setBounds` which can be done using this layout only (I guess).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class clothes2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JTextField n=null;
    JButton m=null;

    public clothes2(){
        initComponents();
    }

    public void initComponents() {
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320,200));
        jp.setLayout(null);
        m=new JButton("add");
        m.setBounds(0,0,50,50);
        jp.add(m);
        m.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {

            int x=0;
            int y=0;

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
                x+=100;
                y+=100;
                jp.add(n=new JTextField("Name"));
                n.setBounds(x, y, 50, 50);
                jp.add(n=new JTextField("code"));
                x+=100;
                n.setBounds(x,y, 50, 50);
                jp.revalidate();
                jp.repaint();
                x=0;
            }
        });

        int v = ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS;
        int h = ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS;
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jp, v, h);
        contentPane.add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f= new clothes2();
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.setSize(640,320);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: _I don't wish to use this layout_ - good idea, simply follow it :-) What you are doing manually (align, size and position) _is_ the job of a LayoutManager, find one that does that job properly.

Comment: It seems this code is attempting to create a series of big square text fields (all the same width & height) in a column starting at the top left of the GUI.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Set preferred size of the container.

Comment: guys i have tried the preferred size as well
this is the link to my code

https://www.yousendit.com/download/M3BuS3hmYWJlM1M5TE1UQw

thanks

Comment: i have tried the preferred size before as well but it didn't work. kindly check the code.

Answer (score 2):

JScrollBar uses the preferred size of the component inside it to determine how large the scroll bars should be, and if they should be displayed.

Usually, the layout manager handles this using the preferredLayoutSize method. This can be overriden by explicitly setting the preferred size of the component.

So either you have to set the preferred size, or use a custom layout manager that calculates it for you.

see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949363/java-layout-for-displaying-panels-dynamically-with-scroll-bar)

might help you.

Comment: guys i have tried the preferred size as well
this is the link to my code

https://www.yousendit.com/download/M3BuS3hmYWJlM1M5TE1UQw

thanks

Comment: i have tried the preferred size before as well but it didn't work. kindly check the code.

Comment: If it is less than 1 KB of code, please just edit it into the question, rather than link to it!  (I've done that.)

Answer (score 2):

> display dynamic objects .. which can be done using this layout only (I guess).

You guess wrong.

See [this GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), that can not only change PLAFs at run-time, but also dynamically add new components<sup>1</sup>.  Click to..

<kbd>Add Another Label</kbd>

[image]

1. This example adds the new labels to a `GridLayout` - but the principle is the same for any layout (or any component).

Comment: what i meant to say is that i want to put dynamic objects ! yes it can be done by others as well ! agreed. have tried with grid layout.
but i have to provide margin. have to align them properly. 

its not about just throwing objects on the panel. That is why am using absolute layout, so that i can use setBounds
.
have searched about group layout as well but was unsuccessful in adding dynamic objects.

Comment: *"its not about just throwing objects on the panel."*  Of course not, but then, you don't 'throw them' onto the panel, where exactly do you put them?  If you can describe that in words, I am confident we can determine a J2SE or 3rd party layout that will accommodate that component positioning in a dynamic way.  I did not mean the `GridLayout` was the ultimate answer for your use-case, that is why I added (& a little louder this time) *This example adds the new labels to a GridLayout - but the principle is the same for **any layout** (or any component).*

Answer (score 0):

add layout
`jp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`