# Java Swings GUI, changing the display based on which button is clicked. What is the ideal way to implement this?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I'm pretty new to programming Java based GUI applications. Here's what I have in mind, I want to divide the window into two areas.
The first are contains buttons (or a list), and based on which button was clicked, or which item was selected, the second area changes. (finite number of buttons)
Something like this:

[image]

I can think of many ways to do this, but I am not sure what is the best practice. Do I have several invisible panels and make only 1 panel visible at a time, or do I change the ordering (bring panel x to front), or is there some other way?

Appreciate any help I receive!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are trying to implement something like a `JTabbedPane`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this is a primarily opinion-based answer I'd go with a [Nested Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/how-to-add-jtable-in-jpanel/5630271#5630271) approach:

- Main panel with [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). Or you can use the frame's content pane which already has `BorderLayout` as default layout manager.
- Left panel with [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) (or [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)).
- Right panel with [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

***Note***: Buttons in the left panel should switch right panels cards.

See [Lesson: Layoing Out Components within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/) tutorial.

---

For complex GUIs you have also third-party layout managers available, listed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18749449/1795530):

- [MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/)
- [DesignGridLayout](https://designgridlayout.java.net/)
- [FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/)

Comment: Additionaly you may want to use [JSplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) to place left and right panels.