# Which Swing Layout is using it?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, resize

I'm developing a ScoreBoard in Java and I'm using Swing for the UI.

I already have done it, but I need to resize all components while resizing the window, keeping the components size proportion. You can understand what I want looking this other Scoreboard application which already exists. This Scoreboard has exactly the desired behaviour that I want for mine. Look:

- 1st window size example -> http://oi62.tinypic.com/21orjmw.jpg
- 2nd window size example -> http://oi60.tinypic.com/33peezq.jpg
- 3rd window size example -> http://oi61.tinypic.com/iw3ic9.jpg
- 4th window size example -> http://oi59.tinypic.com/4r566t.jpg

As you can see, the proportions are always the same.

I know that the only way to do this is using Layouts, but it's chaotic for me. Which one should I use? Can anybody help me, please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: MigLayout/GridBagLayout and possible `FlowLaout` and `BorderLayout`...

Comment: *Which one should I use?* Tipically we don't use a single layout manager but a [combination of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/1795530) (see the great example in the linked answer). Also see the list of third-party layout managers presented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18749449/1795530)