# Assigning text field name to variable amount of text fields

Tags: java, swing, variables

My program starts by prompting the user to enter the number of masses they would like to orbit

```
public class textEvent1 implements ActionListener {    //action listener for "how many masses?"
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            n = (int)(Double.parseDouble(massNumField.getText()));


            submit1.setVisible(false);          //removes text event 1 text from screen
            massNumLabel.setVisible(false);
            massNumField.setVisible(false);
```

Then with that information I create that number of labels and text fields like so

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {                                  //adds text event 2 text to the screen
                    massLabel = new JLabel("How much mass does Mass " +i+ " have? ");
                    massField = new JTextField(5);

                    xCorLabel = new JLabel("What is mass "+i+"'s starting x-coordinate?");
                    xCorField = new JTextField(5);

                    yCorLabel = new JLabel("what is mass "+i+"'s starting y-coordinate?");
                    yCorField = new JTextField(5);

                    xVelLabel = new JLabel("What is mass "+i+"'s starting x velocity?");
                    xVelField = new JTextField(5);

                    yVelLabel = new JLabel("What is mass "+i+"'s starting y velocity?");
                    yVelField = new JTextField(5);

                    add(massLabel);
                    add(massField);

                    add(xCorLabel);
                    add(xCorField);

                    add(yCorLabel);
                    add(yCorField);

                    add(xVelLabel);
                    add(xVelField);

                    add(yVelLabel);
                    add(yVelField);
                }
```

Now my problem is reading from these text fields with with another actionlistner (a submit button) and assigning the value entered into an array. Since I dont know how many masses there will be I dont know how many text fields there will be and each text field essentially has the same name, how do I assign say the value entered for mass2's mass when its text field has the same name as all the other text fields?

Comment: Use Arrays for each of the text fields.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14858272/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<JTextField>` for each piece of data you need.

So add to your class the instance variables:

```
List<JTextField> masses, xCors, yCors, xVels, yVels;
```

Initialize them (ArrayLists probably work fine here), then in that `actionPerformed` method where you create the JTextFields, add them one by one to the Lists:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    massLabel = new JLabel("How much mass does mass " +i+ " have? ");
    massField = new JTextField(5);
    masses.add(massField);

    /* .. initialize all other fields similarly, adding them to the Lists */
```

When you want to read values from / assign values to the text fields, you can access them from the Lists using `masses.get(i)`.

Comment: Im having trouble collecting the data from the different lists. In the next part of my program I try to collect the proper component from a list say the masses list and assign it to a double variable to construct an object. I tried casting it as a double, using Double.parseDouble(masses.get(i).getText())......any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on the error? Also, did you make sure to still call `add(massField);` when creating the text fields?

Comment: Ive been having a bunch of trouble with this one. I think I found the answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854842/reading-arraylist-jtextfields/18857945?noredirect=1#18857945)

Comment: everything kiheru says in [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854842/reading-arraylist-jtextfields/18857945?noredirect=1#18857945) is correct. List indices start at 0, so if you have 4 masses, their indices are at 0-3, meaning that calling `masses.get(4)` attempts to access an index outside the list, hence the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. The enhanced foreach loop is also good advice, as is using the foreach with generics so you don't have to worry about casting

Comment: do you think it is possible to do this with just a regular for loop (assign the textfield value to a variable)? I tried doing it with a bunch of cascading for-each loops and later I found out it was only assigning the final element of each list to my final array