# reading ArrayList JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextfield

My program starts by prompting the user how many text fields they would like to have

```
public class textEvent1 implements ActionListener {    //action listener for "how many masses?"
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                n = (int)(Double.parseDouble(massNumField.getText()));
```

next I create a for loop to create labels and textfields (which I have created lists for because I dont know how many there will be). There are a couple of lists but I will give an example of just one.

```
ArrayList masses = new ArrayList();

    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {                                  //adds text event 2 text to the screen
                        massLabel = new JLabel("How much mass does Mass " +i+ " have? ");
                        massField = new JTextField(5);
                        masses.add(massField);
```

Now my problem appears to come when I try to assign an element of the masses list to a variable like so.

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
                        mass =  Double.parseDouble(((JTextComponent) masses.get(i)).getText());
```

I have tried a couple of things...mass = masses.get(i).....mass = masses.get(i).getText()) and so on and so on. I either keep getting errors such as Null pointer exceptions or things saying I cant parseDouble an Object.

There errors that arrise for this example are as below

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 3
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at acmx.export.java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:54)
    at Orbit$textEvent2.actionPerformed(Orbit.java:151)
```

line 151 is

```
mass =  Double.parseDouble(((JTextComponent) masses.get(i)).getText());
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include how you're creating and setting up the `masses` variable? I suspect that may be the issue. (Hit the `edit` button in the lower-left of your question)

Comment: *"Any suggestions would be very useful."*  I suggest you ask a question..  Also:  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the `JTextFields`, you do:

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    ...
```

Note that `List` indices start at 0, so when you retrieve the items with a similar loop, using `i` as the index, you are trying to access one past the last item. Change the reading loop indices to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ...
```

Or you could use an enhance for loop, unless you need to use an ancient java version:

```
for (Object massField : masses) {
    mass =  Double.parseDouble(((JTextComponent) massField).getText());
    ...
```

(Then you should really use generics too, if the java version supports them).

Comment: Btw, is there a particular reason to not use `ArrayList<JTextField>`? That would save the cast and be good for type safety.

Comment: ya I tried that and for some strange reason it didn't accept it. it came up with a warning saying "The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <JTextField>"

Comment: @DavidJarrin looks like you're importing the wrong `ArrayList`. It should be `java.util.ArrayList`