# Where can I find tools for building groups for GroupLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, grouplayout

In many cases, a `GroupLayout` may include pieces with simple structures. For example, it seems sensible to write something like an `AlignedStack` object that would allow the user to put together a bunch of components/groups/gaps making up a left/center/right-aligned vertical or top/center/bottom aligned horizontal "stack" and then retrieve the resulting horizontal and vertical groups. I can surely write what I need myself (it seems like fairly trivial boilerplate), but I'm wondering if anyone's built a package of such things so I don't have to.

Comment: *"something like an `AlignedStack`"* DYM like seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21659516/418556)?  I've never heard of an `AlignedStack`, link to documentation.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow; can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what an "aligned stack" is, but if I do then you should be able to use a `BoxLayout`. It does horizontal and vertical positioning and components can be top/bottom or left/right aligned.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: A `BoxLayout` has to lay out its own `Container`. That's certainly an option, but in this case it seems more natural to me to have two `BoxLayout`-like `Group`s as part of a `GroupLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Several approaches are common:

- This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504753/230513) nests panels having `GroupLayout` in a panel having a vertical `BoxLayout`.
- This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14858272/230513) illustrates how to add rows dynamically to a panel having `GroupLayout`.
- The NeBeans and Eclipse GUI editors are useful for experimenting; examine the generated code to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try Eclipse WindowBuilder ( https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/ ). It can build any swing layout for you, featuring a pretty smart code parser / generator, all swing components and layouts, and an easy to use drag and drop / property based editor. I think it will suit your needs.

Comment: This does not relate to the question I intended to ask. Such an editor will *not* meet my needs for this particular layout.

Comment: How so? I'm sorry but from your question I assumed you needed a "tool." What do you actually want? If you have already tried windowbuilder please explain why it doesn't meet your needs. If not, please try it before assuming it won't work.