# Java Group layout, vertical layout issues

Tags: java, swing, vertical-alignment, layout-manager, grouplayout

I am trying to make a two column, 3 row layout. Something along the lines of:

```
----------------------
| Username |Textbox| |
| Email    |Textbox| |
----------------------
```

Yet even when I'm quite sure the groups managed correctly, it still ends up on a single row like so:
[image: Single Row]

I have the vertical groups separated just fine

```
gl_contentPanel.setHorizontalGroup(
        gl_contentPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                           .addComponent(usernameLabel)
                           .addComponent(emailLabel))
                  .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                           .addComponent(usernames)
                           .addComponent(email))
             );
        gl_contentPanel.setVerticalGroup(
                gl_contentPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                   .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(usernameLabel)
                        .addComponent(usernames))
                   .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(emailLabel)
                        .addComponent(email))
             );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the layout for the container - see mark [1] in the third line below.
To me it looks like you missed that and the container uses FlowLayout.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("GroupLayout Test");
GroupLayout gl_contentPanel = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
frame.setLayout(gl_contentPanel); // [1]

JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("User name");
JLabel emailLabel = new JLabel("Email");
JTextField usernames = new JTextField("usernames");
JTextField email = new JTextField("email");

// your snippet
gl_contentPanel.setHorizontalGroup(
        gl_contentPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                               .addComponent(usernameLabel)
                               .addComponent(emailLabel))
                      .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                               .addComponent(usernames)
                               .addComponent(email))
                 );
    gl_contentPanel.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPanel.createSequentialGroup()
               .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(usernameLabel)
                    .addComponent(usernames))
               .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(emailLabel)
                    .addComponent(email))
         );
// end of your snippet

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: +1 good catch; see also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11284874/230513), which adds a third row.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, there's a working example of a two column, three row layout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504753/230513), illustrated below, that may help guide you.

[image]