# Positioning GUI objects on a Frame

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

I am developing a Java application and would like some help in positioning some Labels and TextFields.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextField; 
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class AuctionClient
{
public AuctionClient()
{
    JFrame GUIFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel GUIPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel LabelUserName = new JLabel("UserName:");
    JTextField TextFieldUserName = new JTextField("                               ");

    JLabel LabelPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
    JTextField TextFieldPassword = new JTextField("                               ");        

    GUIFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GUIFrame.setTitle("Auction Client");
    GUIFrame.setSize(500,250);

    GUIFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    GUIPanel.add(LabelUserName);
    GUIPanel.add(TextFieldUserName);        

    GUIPanel.add(LabelPassword);
    GUIPanel.add(TextFieldPassword);         

    GUIFrame.add(GUIPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    GUIFrame.setVisible(true);
}  
}
```

With the above code, the LabelPassword and TextFieldPassword is on the same line as the LabelUsername and TextFieldUsername. Can I please have some help to position the LabelPassword and TextFieldPassword on a new line. Is it possible to specify X,Y coordinates to position objects on a JFrame?

Here is an image to show you how the objects are currently being shown:

[image]

http://canning.co.nz/Java/Positioning_Image.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never try to position components with coordinates. Rather use appropriate `LayoutManager's` and use logical conditions and constraints to position your components.

Here is one example using `GridBagLayout`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AuctionClient {
    public AuctionClient() {
        JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();
        JPanel guiPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel userNameLabel = new JLabel("UserName:");
        JTextField userNameTextField = new JTextField(30);

        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        JTextField passwordTextField = new JPasswordField(30);

        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("Auction Client");
        guiFrame.setSize(500, 250);

        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        GridBagConstraints labelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        labelGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
        GridBagConstraints fieldGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        fieldGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
        fieldGBC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        guiPanel.add(userNameLabel, labelGBC);
        guiPanel.add(userNameTextField, fieldGBC);

        guiPanel.add(passwordLabel, labelGBC);
        guiPanel.add(passwordTextField, fieldGBC);

        guiFrame.add(guiPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AuctionClient();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

- [GridLayout, SpringLayout, GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) can do that by default
- easiest coud be [GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html),

  1. but every JComponents are resizable with its container
  2. have to change horizontal alingment for JLabel (`setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);` or `setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);`)
  3. determine (`JTextField TextFieldUserName = new JTextField(20`)) initial Dimension for any of `LayoutManager`

Comment: Also consider `GroupLayout `, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8504753/230513).

Comment: I like the dots you put because you can't only post a smile. +1