# JPane inside JScrolledPane. No vertical scrollbar when needed

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

ive got a JPane within a JScrolledPane. When i add content to  JPane , JScrollPane doesnt show scrollbar. I tried repaint() and revalidate() but it didnt help.

```
static void ladowaniePaneli()
    {
    int b;
    for(b=0;b<o;b++)
        {
        bgPanel[b] = new JBackgroundPanel();
        nowyPanel[b] = new JPanel();

        ((FlowLayout)bgPanel[b].getLayout()).setVgap(0);
        nowyPanel[b].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(790,518));
        nowyPanel[b].setOpaque(false);

        vertical[b] = new JScrollPane(nowyPanel[b]);
        vertical[b].setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        vertical[b].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(789,517));
        vertical[b].setOpaque(false);
        vertical[b].getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        bgPanel[b].add(vertical[b]);           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense that scrollbars are never seen since you restrict the size of the contained component so that it's always trivially larger than the scrollopane's viewport:

```
nowyPanel[b].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(790,518));
```

Solution: don't do that.

Comment: (or use the Scrollable interface)

Comment: im using flowLayout. if i dont use setPreferredSize method components wont warp to another line.
quess the answer for that is trying another layout but i dont know layouts that well. could anyone at least tell me which layout would be best for this? Im adding JButtons + JTextAreas there.

Comment: @RobertKubisiak The best layout will depend on what it is you're trying to achieve

Comment: @MadProgrammer im trying to add components in pairs of JButton+JTextArea.. no horizontal scrolling. just vertical. pairs should be warped to new line if they exceed JScrollPane width

Comment: +1 for getting the OP to listen to the suggestion. @RobertKubisiak, you were given this advice in you last question by MadProgrammer. Please pay attention to all answers given when you ask a question.

Comment: @RobertKubisiak `GridBagLayout` is probably your best shot. Here is an example that displays several pairs of label and textfield: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397609/positioning-gui-objects-on-a-frame/16397844#16397844

Comment: @Guillaume Polet i just used it. worked perfectly. 
thx everyone for help

Answer (score 3):

> if i dont use setPreferredSize method components wont warp to another line

You can try the [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/).

> pairs should be warped to new line if they exceed JScrollPane width

Components are layed out individually. I you want a group of components to wrap then you would need to add the components to a separate panel first. Then add the panel to the panel using the WrapLayout.

Comment: dont know why but wrap layout didnt work for me. i just learned how to use GridBagLayout and it worked. But thx for advice :)