# Align 2 sets/items on either side of center

Tags: java, swing, alignment, center, layout-manager

I'm trying to figure out the best way to align 2 sets of items in the center of a panel in a Java Swing application.  The panel is in the `North` position of a `BorderLayout` whose width is determined by the `JTextField` in the `Center` position of the layout.  The problem I'm having is, I have a set of labels and smaller text fields that I want to center so that the end of the label and the start of the first text field meet at the center of the panel.

I've tried `GroupLayout`, but ended up with the following result:
[image]

Note: *The 2 text fields separated by a + are in a sub-panel.*

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:
[image]

Apparently I'm either missing something, or this is far more complicated than necessary to do.  I actually run into this issue a LOT!  I'm surprised there isn't a special grid layout specifically for this.

Trying to do this with a `GridLayout` resulted in this:
[image]

So... what **IS** the easiest way to get the layout I'm looking for (second image)?

`GroupLayout` example code below:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setContentPane(panel);

    JPanel longText = new JPanel();
    JPanel shortText = new JPanel();
    JPanel mediumText = new JPanel();

    longText.add(new TextField(5));
    longText.add(new JLabel("+"));
    longText.add(new TextField(5));
    shortText.add(new TextField(5));
    shortText.add(new JLabel("+"));
    shortText.add(new TextField(5));
    mediumText.add(new TextField(5));
    mediumText.add(new JLabel("+"));
    mediumText.add(new TextField(5));

    JLabel lExample = new JLabel("Long text example:");
    JLabel sExample = new JLabel("Short:");
    JLabel mExample = new JLabel("Medium Example:");

    JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(subPanel);
    subPanel.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.CENTER)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(lExample)
                    .addComponent(sExample)
                    .addComponent(mExample))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(longText)
                    .addComponent(shortText)
                    .addComponent(mediumText))))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
            .addComponent(lExample)
            .addComponent(longText))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
            .addComponent(sExample)
            .addComponent(shortText))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
            .addComponent(mExample).addComponent(mediumText))
    );

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea() {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600,300);
        }
    };
    textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setAutoscrolls(true);

    panel.add(subPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(textArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Also consider `GroupLayout`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8504753/230513).

Comment: Added my code that was returning the `GroupLayout` result.  @MadProgrammer: could you provide an example of how to do this with GridBagLayout?  I may be thinking of an old Photoshop JavaScript UI instead, but I recall the labels and text fields not lining up the last time I got them to meet in the middle.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), as it gives you a lot more control over the placement of individual components and respects the preferred size of the components where it can (unless you override them through the use of the `GridBagConstraints`)

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class LayoutExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LayoutExample();
    }

    public LayoutExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JLabel longText = new JLabel("Long Text Example");
            JLabel shortText = new JLabel("Short Example");
            JLabel medText = new JLabel("Medium Example");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(longText, gbc);
            addFields(gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(shortText, gbc);
            addFields(gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(medText, gbc);
            addFields(gbc);
        }

        protected void addFields(GridBagConstraints gbc) {
            JTextField field1 = new JTextField("0", 5);
            field1.setEnabled(false);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(field1, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 4, 0, 4);
            add(new JLabel("+"), gbc);
            JTextField field2 = new JTextField(5);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(field2, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Very nice!  That lined them up nicely.  Thank you very much!