# GroupLayout needs a Container for its constructor

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

I'm reading about Java GUI topics, while I'm reading about `GroupLayout` I found that it needs a Container object. However what I understood that the `LayoutManager` is used to layout may container, so I need to set what is the layout for my container, but in group layout I must set the Container which the group layout will manage.

Do I understand something wrong or there is no misunderstanding?

Comment: Generally a GroupLayout is used by an IDE to create a layout. All components are added to a single panel. This makes the code hard to manage if you ever switch to a different IDE. As individuals we can logically group components into different panels each using a different layout manager. This makes the code more structured and easier to maintain.  I suggest you read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and learn the basic layout managers first. There is a working example for the GroupLayout that should answer your question.

Comment: More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8504753/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. `GroupLayout` is instantiated differently.

`GroupLayout`:

```
Container pane = getContentPane();
GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
pane.setLayout(gl);
```

`MigLayout`:

```
setLayout(new MigLayout());
```

But it is only a technical detail.