# Java Swing GroupLayout align component with parent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, grouplayout

I've built a JFrame with two panels aligned like this:

panel1

panel2

So their width matches. But panel2's width is greater than panel1's would be. Therefore the panel is stretched but not the components inside.
I've built up panel1's layout with a group layout like this:

```
label1 label2

label3 label4

               button1 #### <-- there is still space but the button does not align with its parent's right
```

Here's my code:

```
GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);
layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(label1)
                        .addComponent(label2))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(label3)
                        .addComponent(label4)))
        .addComponent(button1, GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING));

layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(label1)
                .addComponent(label2))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(label3)
                .addComponent(label4))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(button1)));

setLayout(layout);
```

Is there any way to use all the space available? Shouldn't this be the default behavior?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and an image of what you want

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8504753/230513).

Comment: If you show us what exactly you what to achieve, I can help you. With your current description I don't know what you want.