# How do I lock the size of the components in a re-sizable frame when using GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I want to make the frame resizable but keep the initial size of components in a GridLayout. How do I do this?

Initial Size. This is the size I want to keep:

[image]

When the frame is resized, the size of the components changes. I don't want this:

[image]

Comment: Put the container inside a second container, use a `GridBagLayout` to layout the second container onto the parent, without constraints.  `GridBagLayout` will continue to layout the components to their preferred size and centre the second container within the parent when more space is avaliable

Comment: Alternatively, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504753/230513) uses `GroupLayout` to get useful resizing.

Comment: I have to use GridLayout because it's a requirement

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you show me an example? I don't understand

Comment: @David Create a new JPanel, set its layout as a GridBagLayoit, add your existing panel to it, then add the new panel to your parent container

Comment: JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);

  panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
  
  JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
  panel2.add(panel1);
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);

Comment: `frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);` No. If following the suggestion of @MadProgrammer, that should be `panel1.add(panel2);`

Comment: "Could you show me an example?"  - post an [mcve]. This makes helping much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates a solution using `GridBagLayout` [as proposed by MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671241/how-do-i-lock-the-size-of-the-components-in-a-re-sizable-frame-when-using-gridla#comment98028706_55671241).
Including such mcve in the **question** makes helping much easier and your chances to get good answers higher.

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class SwingMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); //place desired content in a GridbagLayout
        frame.add(new TestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class TestPane extends JPanel{

    TestPane() {

        Border padding = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
        setBorder(padding);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10));
        add(new JLabel("Celsius"));
        add(new JTextField(10));
        add(new JLabel("Fahrenheit"));
        add(new JTextField(10));
    }
}
```

[image]