# How does one add a JScrollPane to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have been searching around for an easy way to implement a `JScrollPlane`. I am trying to add it to a `JPanel`, and it will contain a dynamic number of `JPanel`s (which will be filled with other stuff).

Here is my (failing miserably) attempt to make said `JScrollPane`:

```java
final JPanel info = new JPanel();
final JScrollPane infoS = new JScrollPane(info,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
info.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
info.setLocation(10,78);
info.setSize(420,490);
infoS.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
gui.add(infoS);
```

Comment: `gui.add(infoS);`? don't you mean `info.add(infoS)`? oh yeah, and please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html).

Comment: @mre: I hope not, because it would mean that info would be both the child and parent of infoS (and vice-versa).

Comment: Ah, sorry I left that bit of information out. `gui` is the overall JPanel that contains the content of the frame.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem you're having is the fact that the default layout manager's layout is set to `FlowLayout`, which means that the `JScrollPane` will want to use it's preferred size to be layout with, which may not fill the entire panel.

Instead, use a `BorderLayout`

```
final JPanel info = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); // <-- Change me :D
final JScrollPane infoS = new JScrollPane(info,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
// These are bad ideas, setLocation and setSize won't work, as the panel should be
// under the control of a layout manager
//info.setLocation(10,78);
//info.setSize(420,490);
//infoS.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
gui.add(infoS);
```

Comment: After a lot of tinkering and googling, I have gotten it working. Thanks for providing this excellent example!

Answer (score 2):

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3175280/230513), a series of nested panels are added to a panel having `BoxLayout`. That panel is used to create a `JScrollPane` which is then added to a `JFrame`.

```
public class BoxTest extends JPanel {
...
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(this,
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
...
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.add(jsp); // BorderLayout.CENTER, by default
```

Comment: I think I remember coming across that at one point. However it isn't what I'm looking for. This makes the entire frame a JScrollPane. I just want a specific JPanel to become a JScrollPane.

Comment: @Thrfoot The principle is still the same.  `JFrame` is just a component after all (well, actually, it defers to the content pane, but...)

Comment: @Thrfoot: No, the `JScrollPane` is added to the frame's content pane.