# JScrollPane- Only Vertical Scroll?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jsplitpane, jscrollbar

I have the following line of code:

```
JSplitPane VPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,(new class1()),new JScrollPane(new class2()));
```

I'd like class2 to ONLY have vertical scrolling please? Since my layout falls to bits otherwise.
I am using GridBagLayout and it's too late to change the layout now. Is there a method to fix this?

Comment: `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER `, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13462570/230513).

Comment: Really sorry, I just tried and I'm struggling to implement this.
The above is SSCCE. Can you just show me the implementation please?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work- I'm just getting errors =[

Comment: *"The above is SSCCE"*  The code in this question is a (single line) code snippet, not an SSCCE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

+1 to trashgods comment.

> It doesn't seem to work- I'm just getting errors =[

To illustrate this:

```
JScrollPane js=...; //Create a variable reference to the an instance of scrollpane

JSPlitPane jsp;

js.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);//set the horizontal scrollbar to never appear

jsp=new JSplitPane(..,js);//create the splitpane with the jscrollpane etc
```

**UPDATE**

I would recommend creating references to your variables/components especially because you might want to modify them dynamically later.