# How to remove excess space at bottom

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, grid-layout, flowlayout

I'm creating a simple Java Swing application. The build set up is a Grid Layout of 3 rows and 1 column. Inside the top row is another Grid Layout that has two columns, and inside each of those columns another Grid Layout splitting it into 2 rows. Same thing goes for the middle row. The bottom row is just a Flow Layout.

[image]

Black = 3 Rows, Blue = Splitting rows into 2 columns, Red = Splitting two columns into 2 rows.
Here's the actual picture of the output:

[image]

```
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
JPanel botPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
```

My question is, how do I make the bottom row with the button not have the giant gap in it, but end at the bottom of the button?

Comment: Thanks, it worked out really nicely!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html), ra‌​ther than `GridLayout`, for the enclosing panel. Examples may be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#eg) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3175280/230513).

Answer (score 4):

change contentPane from (3,1) to (2,1)

add contentPane to the frame at BorderLayout.CENTER

add botPane to the frame at BorderLayout.SOUTH

then frame.pack()