# Using Flow layout for Check-Boxes

Tags: java, python, swing, awt, jython

I'm trying to use grid layout in my gui to align the Check-boxes one below the other in Jython, even if i use setLocation function, i can't align them properly, is there any other way to do that?

```
from javax.swing import *
from java.awt import *

class Example:

    def __init__(self):

        print "inside class"
        frame = JFrame("Window1")
        frame.setSize(600, 600)
        frame.setResizable(0)
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
        frame.setLayout(FlowLayout())


        label = JLabel("check buttons are here")
        frame.add(label)

        chkb1 = Checkbox("script1")
        chkb1.setLocation(100, 300)
        chkb2 = Checkbox("script2")
        chkb1.setLocation(100, 400)
        chkb3 = Checkbox("script3")
        chkb1.setLocation(100, 500)

        frame.add(chkb1)
        frame.add(chkb2)
        frame.add(chkb3)


        frame.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        obj=Example();
        print __name__
```

Thank you

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Use a `GridLayout` for that column of check boxes.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [`Box`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) with `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3175280/230513).

Comment: Thanks @trashgod, but i'm doing that in Jython. I never used Box layout, I'll try with that now.

Comment: If successful, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188) for the benefit of the Jython community.

Comment: i messed up with Jython, so i went back to Tkinter in python.
Thank you